# Show Selected value from spinner in one activity to the textview in another activity

Tags: android

I know there are few questions similar to mine and I have tried all the suggested solutions mentioned in the existing questions however it's still not working. Pretty sure I'm doing something wrong logically but unable to figure out where. Please point me to right direction.

Spinner activity code method

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent main = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
        Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
        String chosenAppType = appliancestypespinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        myBundle.putString("appliance type spinner",chosenAppType);


        main.putExtra("chose appliance type", myBundle);
        startActivity(main);

    }
```

`TextView Activity` (getting the spinner value as string in `textview` (`tvApplianceType = textview` )

```
Bundle myBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(myBundle == null)
    {
        return;         
    }

    String str_recieved_appType = myBundle.getString("appliance type spinner");
    if (str_recieved_appType != null)
    {
        tvApplianceType.setText(str_recieved_appType);
    }
}
```

Just to add that I'm also passing the value of Edittext present from the Spinner activity  to the same textview that i'm passing the spinner value to that EditText to TextView is working fine. Is it not working because i'm using the same textview for both operations however either operation need to work at one time :/. So either edittext to textView OR  spinner to textview.

Edittext Code

```
String str_appliance_type = et_input_Appliance_Type.getText().toString().trim();
if (!str_appliance_type.equals(""))
                {

                    data.add(str_appliance_type );
                    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data );
                    appliancestypespinner.setAdapter(aa);

                    //passing edittext value to MainActivity class 
                    Bundle carrier = new Bundle();
                    Intent i = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("appliance type",str_appliance_type);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
```

Passing Value fro Editext to textview

```
//getting the edittext value from inputAppliance class
    Bundle carrier = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(carrier == null)
    {
        return;         
    }

    String str_recieved = carrier.getString("appliance type");
    if (str_recieved != null)
    {
        tvApplianceType.setText(str_recieved);
    }
```

Comment: try this ... main.putExtra(myBundle);

Comment: It will give an error as putExtra() requires String and Bundle as paramters.

Comment: @user3677683 use putExtras()

Comment: @user3677683 accept the answer which helped you then it will be easy for others who come across same problem.

Comment: Tried but no joy mate.

Comment: Sorry Aniruddha, I was trying all the answers however no answer is working currently :(

Comment: @user3677683 are you getting any errors

Comment: Not syntax error, just logical which means when I select a value from spinner it doesn't go to the MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = appliancestypespinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); // I assume this line is proper.

Intent i = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("your_key",  str);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

In MainActivity

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String s = b.getString("your_key");
your_textView.setText(s);
```

Comment: Tried it but no luck still :(

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting the value from spinner in String str?

Comment: Yes, I'm. It doesn't do anything at all as it suppose to go to MainActivity automatically upon selection of a value but it doesn't. It stays on the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 main.putExtra("chose appliance type", myBundle);
 startActivity(main);
```

to

```
 main.putExtras(myBundle);
 startActivity(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent main = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
main.putExtra("SELECTED_DATA", appliancestypespinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
startActivity(main);
```

In Another Activity:

```
String data=this.getIntent.getStringExtra("SELECTED_DATA");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Intent:

Spinner Activity:

```
Intent calculate = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class);
calculate.putExtra("carry_name", entername.getText().toString());
```

On Second Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

            String name = intent.getStringExtra("carry_name");
            congrates.setText("Congratulation  " + name);
```

Comment: I tried, still not working mate :(, i'm having doubts now.. IS WHAT I'M TRYING TO ACHIEVE EVEN POSSIBLE IN ANDROID :/ :(

Comment: Its very simple, you can achieve it in 4-5 line, but you are trying a very complicated process.

Comment: Can you please tell me a simple approach as i just need to pass the value of selected text value from the spinner in SpinnerActivty. Upon selecting the value it should automatically go to the MainActivity and display the spinner value in the textview of MainActivity. Working on this issue since 9am :( however not getting any. Please tell me an easier process.

Comment: I have created a project for you, just share your E-mail id. I will send it to you

Comment: zain_afzal000@hotmail.co.uk. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your efforts. By the way I got mine working. However, please do send me the project as I want to learn new and efficient way to do it.

Comment: Good to hear this, that you have completed it by yourself.

Comment: Yes, please do send me the project too :)